# Passing Windows User Credentials to Web Service

Tags: web-services, reporting-services, windows-authentication

I have a ASP 3.5 web forms app using windows authentication that needs to call a soap based web service (the SSRS 2005 report service) which uses integrated windows authentication. However the call to the web service from the asp backend keeps throwing a 401 error. 
If I turn on anonymous authenticatoin on the web service it works ok using the IUSR_xxx account however I want it to connect using the windows account of the user accessing the asp web app. How can I pass through the windows user credentials?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have to authenticate your webservice by supplying the default credential to your proxy. like this

```
localhost.ServiceX myProxy = new localhost.ServiceX();
myProxy.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
```

Comment: yeah tried that but it the same 401 error is returned, the DefaultCredentials doesn't seem to contain the credentials of the current windows user

Comment: Ok that worked however I also needed to explicitly set the ImpersonationLevel property on the web service proxy WebRequest object to Impersonation. By default it was set to Delegation.

Comment: You can also use: myProxy.UseDefaultCredentials = True